# How to compile Mono with vb.net support

Tags: vb.net, mono

I've downloaded latest source from mono project, compiled it and everything works (c# projects, mod_mono, xsp) except vb.net. Vbnc, mono's vb.net compiler does not exist after compiling mono from source.

This is on CentOS 5, on Ubuntu 10.04 I installed mono packages via apt-get and vb.net just works.

What am I missing, or how to get vb.net support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mono's VB.Net support is in a separate module.

Either download the 'mono-basic' tarball:
http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/sources-stable/

or get it directly from SVN:
http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mono-basic/

or you can simply copy over what you need from a working system, like vbnc.exe and Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.

Comment: Somehow I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All information about VB.NET on Mono is available at http://www.mono-project.com/Language_BASIC

Precompiled VB.NET assemblies can just be run with Mono.

The Mono VB.NET compiler is called vbnc.

If you need further help, can you please specify what exactly doesn't work? Does the compiler executable not exist, will VB.NET programs not run, or are you referring to MonoDevelop support?

(If the latter, make sure you have the latest MonoDevelop...)